# how to style on messenger chat with react

Tags: reactjs, facebook-messenger

So i've not find anything to inside  to change the size of messenger chat button. I want to just use simple as possible that

```
import MessengerCustomerChat from 'react-messenger-customer-chat';  

return (
    <ContainerComp>
            <Header/>
            <Banner/>
            <Solutions/>
            <Features/>
            <Industries/>
            <MessengerCustomerChat
                pageId="331581003847973"
                appId="613554456622921"
                themeColor={'#8753F0'}  // size, style={{width:20px}} something like but not worked. 
            />,

            <Footer/>

        </ContainerComp>
  )


How to give size? I've tried it.
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work out the way you expected?

Comment: I've tried the give size of messenger button that I've added. Like give to inside <MessengerCustomerChat/>   is not worked as I've expected to make to smaller.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about changing the size. The feature just isn't supported.

Comment: Yes. I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

When using inline style in React you need to set the value as a string. Like this:

```
<MessengerCustomerChat
    pageId="331581003847973"
    appId="613554456622921"
    themeColor={'#8753F0'}, 
    style={{width:"20px"}}
/>,
```

Comment: I've tried exactly that one but still not worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
  chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "331581003847973");
  chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
</script>

<!-- Your SDK code -->
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v12.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fmessengerBtn">

  <!-- Messenger Chat Plugin Code -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat" messenger_app_id="613554456622921"
       page_id="331581003847973" theme_color="#8753F0" minimized="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've just tried to style to change the plugin size on react website because I want to make it small. I saw other website did make it small. I can't just find  anything to give width of size. And also tried to style in index.css to hope may will work. Is there any way to just write code to work on messenger chat plugin for smaller?